# Which devices use UC-E6 plug

Tags: usb, usb-device, plug

I have an in-car charger left after I sold the GPS localizer. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MicroUSB#Connector_types), it uses "*UC-E6 proprietary (non-USB) plug*" (second to the left on [this photo](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d6/Usb_connectors.JPG)).

Does anyone know any device, that uses the same plug. Or is there a DIY kit for assembling such a device? Or maybe someone heard about any adapter, that could be used with this charger and any *standard microUSB device*?

I'm trying to determine, if I can find any usage for this charger or if I should throw it away, since I got rid of the original device (GPS localizer),that used it.

Comment: You mean other than Nikon cameras?

Comment: I didn't knew, Nikon uses it. But, yeap -- I was rather thinking about devices that can be more like used in car (since this is in-car charger, plugged directly to car's electrical system). Like a smartphone, tablet, GPS navigation, MP3 or video player, audio system, car's camera (recording as you drive) etc. Photo cameras are rather on the end of such list (unless you do a lot of photos in your car -- Google Street View? :]). I'm talking about constant usage (for which constant power supply would be reasonable) rather than just powering a weak battery in device like a photo camera.

Comment: I haven't heard of an adapter but have you considered snipping the lead and attaching to something else? Micro USB connectors themselves can be a bit tricky to solder but maybe you have a surplus cable sitting around and you can splice / solder the wires together.

Comment: @PeterJ I've asked: "_I'm trying to determine, if I can find any usage for this (...)_". Your suggestion about using microUSB connector seems to be a fully qualified answer. So, please, consider reformulating your comment to an answer, so I can vote it up and accept it, bringing you some reps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't heard of an adapter but you could consider snipping the lead and attaching to something else. Micro USB connectors themselves can be a bit tricky to solder but maybe you have a surplus cable sitting around and you can splice / solder the wires together?

The following photo taken from [Splicing DataBus cables for exterior weatherproof deployment](http://www.ictinternational.com.au/splice.htm) illustrates. That same page also goes into additional detail about achieving a professional result. You may want to invest in some heatshrink tubing but alternatively electrical tape could be used for a "less neat" solution to insulate the wires.

[image: Splicing cables together]

Answer (score 2):

I have a TI-84 Plus Silver Edition graphing calculator that appears to use that EC-U6 plug. Earlier this year my niece was here and none of our USB device-end connectors fit her camera, and now that I think about it, the port was similar to the EC-E6.

The TI-84 manual says "Communication Link:
The TI-84 Plus has a USB port using a USB unit-to-unit cable to connect and communicate with another TI-84 Plus or TI-84 Plus Silver Edition. The TI-84 Plus also has an I/O port using an I/O unit-to-unit cable to communicate with a TI-84 Plus Silver Edition, a TI-84 Plus, a TI-83 Plus Silver Edition, a TI-83 Plus, a TI-83, a TI-82, a TI-73, CBL 2™, or a CBR™ System.
With TI Connect™ software and a USB computer cable, you can also link the TI-84 Plus to a
personal computer.
As future software upgrades become available on the TI Web site, you can download the software to your PC and then use the TI Connect™ software and a USB computer cable to upgrade your TI-84 Plus."

It doesn't say anything about using the port for charging.